# iPhone UITableViewCell: repositioning the textLabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am new to iPhone development and I am currently working on a simple RSS reader app. The problem I am having is that I need to reposition the `textLabel` inside the `UITableViewCells`. I have tried `setFrame` or `setCenter` but it doesn't do anything. Does anyone know what I need to do inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to reposition the `textLabel` at the top of the cell (x = 0, y = 0)?

Thank you

PS: The `UITableViewCell` is referenced by a variable called `cell`. I have tried `[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)]` with no success.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can create a subclass for UITableViewCell and customize de textLabel frame. See that answer: [Labels aligning in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132029/labels-aligning-in-uitableviewcell/1139740#1139740). It's works perfectly to me.

It's my subclass

```
#import "UITableViewCellFixed.h"
@implementation UITableViewCellFixed
- (void) layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
}
@end
```

It's my UITableViewControllerClass:

```
UITableViewCellFixed *cell = (UITableViewCellFixed *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCellFixed alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You really should be setting the label frame to `self.contentView.bounds`

Answer (score 24):

You may try **indentationLevel**, **separatorInset** and other content indentation properties of UITableViewCell object.

Answer (score 10):

Seems I solved my own problem. Here's some code, in case someone runs into the same problem:

```
UILabel *ttitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)] autorelease];
ttitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
ttitle.textColor    = [UIColor blackColor];
ttitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

[ttitle setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle];
```

The idea is to create your own label object, because the textLabel is automatically positioned and can't be moved around.

Cheers.

Comment: This does also break when you remove and add cells to the table as the UILabel doesn't get removed properly.

Comment: A way to fix this breaking is to tag the subviews and remove them after dequeueing the cell by iterating over the subviews. Basically we should just be subclassing, the adding of subviews on cellForRowAtIndexPath is lazier, and more dangerous memory-wise

Answer (score 9):

The reason the original poster's code doesn't work is that it appears that the frame of the textLabel is set after the UITableViewCell has been returned from your delegate method.

I noticed that I can successfully alter many properties of the textLabel, such as the text alignment, color, font, etc, but altering the frame has no effect and when I print the frame to the debugger later (like on select), the frame isn't what I set. Therefore, I conclude that the UIKit framework is altering the frame of the textLabel after it is returned from the delegate method. No doubt this is likely done because Apple engineers wanted to make sure that your text was drawn to the screen, so they measure it and alter the frame so that it will fit. They probably figured that people such as ourselves who wanted to alter the position of the text would be able to do so by subclassing, or simply adding another UILabel (or whatever) as a subview. A novice developer might have a very hard time if his or her text didn't show up in the label or was truncated because they didn't adjust the frame.

In my case, I wanted the text to be center horizontally, to be a specific color/font/size, and to be slightly higher vertically in the cell. Being too lazy to subclass this, I first tried altering the frame. When that didn't work, I tried googling the answer (found this post).

My final solution was to set the numberOfLines property to 0 and add some trailing carriage returns to my text. Now THAT is lazy.

Comment: Upvoted due to being a good summary of the issue. The final solution is horrible though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 it would be

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.textLabel?.frame.origin.x = 50
}
```