# imageView setFrame in table view

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to place my image in location (10,10,60,60).  I write the code but image display from corner.  The code `[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,60,60)];` has no effect.

```
if(indexPath.row==0)
{
    NSString *filepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:pro.s_image ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    //cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    //[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    //[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];

    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,60,60)];

    //  CGRect iframe = cell.imageView.frame;
    //  iframe.size.height = 100.0;
    //  iframe.size.width=100.0;
    //  cell.imageView.frame = iframe;

    cell.imageView.image=image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to subclass UITableViewCell and setting the location of the image in the subclass.

Here's a similar post except they're trying to customize the location of the text label:

[iPhone UITableViewCell: repositioning the textLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984994/iphone-uitableviewcell-repositioning-the-textlabel)

Comment: @thanks bryanmac..... i am trying to do it.... please give me little explanation for -(void) layoutSubviews...

Answer (score 0):

The lazy (bad practive) solution instead of subclassing is to a add a UIImageView to the cell's contentView (and ignore cell.imageView):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
    UIImageView * myCreatedImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12345];
    if (myCreatedImageView==nil) {
      myCreatedImageView=[[UIIimageView alloc]...]
      myCreatedImageView.tag=12345;//identifying tag number
      [self.contentView addSubview:myCreatedImageView];
    }

    //code to manage the image view:
    myCreatedImageView.frame=...
    myCreatedImageView.image=...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to switch the last two lines.
Like this:

```
cell.imageView.image=image;
[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,60,60)];
```

The cell.imageView may be nil before you provide the image.