# how to set the array of text position in cell in UITableview in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray

I have one Mutable array. I want to set the frame of text in UITableView.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.UnitTypeAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 40);
```

Comment: Either create custom UILabel and add in cell.contentView or override layoutSubviews like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984994/iphone-uitableviewcell-repositioning-the-textlabel)

Comment: Yes... I want to add the frame of array text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a new class which inherits UITableViewCell and add the label in cell's contentView property.

change the label's frame in

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

}
```

of your new Cell Class

Comment: I have UITableViewController not UITableViewCell

Comment: @AayushiPanchal You need to create a new class which inherits UITableViewCell and do custom work in it, then you can use it instead of UITableViewCell.