# UITableViewCell's text label alignment to top in IOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, alignment

I am using UITableView.

```
UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = NULL;

tableViewCell = [historyTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Table cells"];
```

Now, how can i set opt alignment to tableViewCell.textlabel?

I tried setFrame too, but it didnt work.

Thanks
Jithendra

Comment: can you post your code for how you have set frame?

Comment: [tableViewCell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]

Comment: opt alignment? Now, What does that mean?

Comment: don't play with tableview's default controls. Try my answer given below.

Comment: Sorry it is TOP alignment. Type mistake

Answer (score 2):

Use [This link](https://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35532-uilabel-vertical-align-on-the-top.html) for verticale alignment text of UILable

otherwise alternative solution of your requirement is ,you can use `UITextField`, the subclass of `UIControl`, which inherits UIControl's the `contentVerticalAlignment` property.

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

You can use this property to align the text on top. You can disable the user from editing the text by using the property `userInteractionEnabled` property.

also here see this [labels-aligning-in-uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132029/labels-aligning-in-uitableviewcell/1139740#1139740) many code

i hope this help you...

Comment: @jithen see this link..http://blog.mick-walker.co.uk/uilabel-vertical-bottom-align

Comment: @jithen also use this class from this link mate https://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35532-uilabel-vertical-align-on-the-top.html

Comment: @jithen see my Updated answer mate with alternative solutions :)

Comment: I have gone through the code. So if i want to set the alignment to TOP, then i have to create instance for VerticallyAlignedLabel and add it to tableViewCell as subview. Please correct me if i am wrong. If this is right, then this is not what i wanted. My question is to set alignment for tableViewCell's default label text position. I can set top position creating new label using UILabel and adding it as subview to tableViewCell..

Comment: yes mate i know so at last i post link for uitableviewcell's lable just go through that link also i give the idea that just add UItextField instead of UILable mate its very easy to use... what you say about it??

Comment: No Mate.. even this is not helping me... Here they are taking third variable UILable , nowhere they used tableViewCell text label. But thanks for ur quick replies..

Comment: mate i'll post code about this with testing my own code .. i use some code with text property of lable and then give some big property to it  i'll post

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
 tableViewCell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; //you can use UITextAlignmentLeft, UITextAlignmentCenter aslo!!
```

For Vertical alignment you need to use `sizeToFit:` method

Also Refer the bellow link

[Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

Comment: `UITextAlignmentRight` is depricated from IOS 6 release, instead use `NSTextAlignmentRight`

Answer (score -4):

You can set TOP align using your default tableViewCell.textlabel through this way

```
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Enjoy Programming

Comment: I can create new UITable instance and add it as subview to tabelviewcell. But my questions is how can i set TOP align using default tableViewCell.textlabel

Comment: try to improve your acccept rate otherwise noone will be ready to help you over stack overflow

Comment: If i find it as good answer, definitely i will accept that reply. Thanks

Comment: I tried this code. But it is not working. Now do u want me to accept it? Sorry...