# ios, UITableView, indent changed unexpectedly after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview, ios7

I have a problem with indention in `UITableView`. [See image to make it clear](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Zu9D9ZQvSVeFpQcnNnRWk1enc/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

There are just cell with `UILabel`.
After launching app, all points have the same indention (like points Schedule & Favourites on picture). But when I scroll it up & then scroll it down back, the indention of labels changes. It appeared in `iOS6` as well as in `iOS7`.

Does anybody have ideas how to fix it?

EDIT0: It seems than only first rendering (before screen is appeared) works well. All others calls "cellForRowAtIndexPath" return incorrect cell view.
Might be it connected w/ constraints... but i'm not sure.

Anyway the way are supposed by NSS works. Thanks everybody for your help.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [activeList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainPointCell";
    OMSMainActiveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.textLabel setText:[activeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Sport aaa... If you really need it :)

Comment: Are you using storyboard? If so, then how many prototype cells are you  using?

Comment: Try to use `OMSMainActiveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: @GoGreen Yes, I use storyboard, there is only one prototype cell.

Comment: Are you really doing anything to helping me or just posting some comments up here. I see no answer from you at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in your custom cell class i. e. in `OMSMainActiveCell`

```
- (void) layoutSubviews 
  {
      [super layoutSubviews];
      self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
  }
```

Also you can [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132029/labels-aligning-in-uitableviewcell/1139740#1139740).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set frame of your label like

```
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x , cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
```

if still its happening then let us know

Comment: I think he is not using custom label! he is using cell's by default textLabel property.

Comment: Do one thing, set the label background color and see its movie or what else happening

Comment: @Retro Yes, it moves left... [Look there](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Zu9D9ZQvSVRTlZdUhoamQ4RFE/edit?usp=sharing) Green label in top-left shows original 20pxl indent.